# How to expand Master Detail in ag grid using separate button?

Tags: ag-grid, ag-grid-react

[image]

How do I show or hide master detail portion using separate button instead of clicking the arrow button in first column? thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the row index of the master row you want to expand -

Call the below onClick of button.

```
showDetail(index) {
    this.gridApi.getDisplayedRowAtIndex(index).setExpanded(true);
}
```

An [example](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-master-detail-detail-grids/#example-keep-detail-rows) from docs where detail grid is expanded in `onFirstDataRendered`